# Node.js express.json middleware not parsing request as expected

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have a simple cURL (i think this is right) that posts a small JSON object to my express server:

```
curl -d "{'test': 'this'}" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

I have express set up as:

```
// set up body parsing in express  to be able  to get parse JSON posts
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded());
```

and have handler that accepts the route:

```
JSON = require('JSON')
module.exports = {
    authenticateUser: function create(req, res){
        var postedObject = req.body
        console.log(postedObject)
        res.send('Handle Post: authenticateUser');
    }
}
```

the handler is getting called, but it is logging the JSON body unexpectedly:

```
{ '{\'test\': \'this\'}': '' }
```

So my entire object looks to be the name side of a JSON Name:Value pair object. no matter what I post it seems to be appending the value side.  Unless  I do something like this:

```
curl -d "a=a" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

which logs:

```
{'a':'a'}
```

so have i not set the right headers? Configured express wrong?  I plan on digging through the express code, but wondered if somebody might know before I find the solution.  Either way having a searchable/indexed answer to this on the web will be nice.

### update 1

ok I need to add the header to the cURL

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'test': 'this'}" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

which gives  the error:

```
Parsing: {'test': 'this'}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at C:\blah\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\json.js:86:19
        at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:blah\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:109:7)
        at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
        at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
        at _stream_readable.js:920:16
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

OR 
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{test: 'this'}" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate

which gives  the error:

```
Parsing: {test: 'this'}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
    at Object.parse (native)
    at C:\blah\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\json.js:86:19
        at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:blah\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:109:7)
        at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
        at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
        at _stream_readable.js:920:16
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

### update 2

in the file connect/lib/middleware/json.js

this line seems to be the one causing issues

```
req.body = JSON.parse(buf, options.reviver);
```

### update 3

I really think it is my cURL

```
buf= JSON.stringify({test: 'This'});
console.log(buf)
req.body = JSON.parse(buf, options.reviver);
```

works logging first 
    {"test":"this"}

and then in my handler:

```
----------------------
{ test: 'this' }
----------------------
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1) JSON middleware only works if the request has `Content-Type: application/json` header.
2) Valid JSON should contain `"`, not `'`.
So it should be `'{"test": "this"}'` instead of `"{'test': 'this'}"`

Try this command:

```
curl -d '{"test": "this"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

Answer (score 6):

THe answer has two pieces

1. add the content header
2. on windows go through the pain  of passing the json correctly, cURL on my windows machine doesn't deal with interchanging the single and double quotes , therefore the proper cURL is

   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"""test""": """this"""}" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate

Yup, inside of the data parameter, you need to use three double quotes to send a single double quote to the server.

Accepting zub's answer, because he is correct.  I was trying a bunch of things to get around windows here.

Comment: Consider a tool like Fiddler.  It will make your work much easier.  http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Answer (score 2):

For those who use postman like me just try to send the request as POST>>RAW and create your Json to do the post, in my test i have created a simple json like this and works:

{
    "name": "test"
}

Using form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows cmd:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"""test""": """this"""}" localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

or use cygwin:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"test": "this"}' localhost:3000/rest/user/authenticate
```

My 2 cents