# Unable to tap into object fields of Json post data in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I am reading the sent, post data to my Nodejs using :

> console.log(req.body.order)

It prints the following data in my console:

> {res_key: kshdkjfh9827349sjdhf, auth_Key: ksjdhfkjs928374sdjkhf923847, customer_id: f, payment_mode: f, getMenuURL: dataurl, orderUID: dfjkh987, has_paid: 0, delivery_discount: 0,  menuOrderData: [{menu_id: 244, menu_price: 4.5, item_name: Cacik (v), menu_quantity: 1, topingsOrder: []}, {menu_id: 240, menu_price: 5, item_name: Marinated Olives (v), menu_quantity: 1, topingsOrder: [{id: 708, name: Water, optional_fee: 2.00}, {id: 710, name: Coke Zero, optional_fee: 2.00}]}, {menu_id: 241, menu_price: 8.5, item_name: Mixed Pickles (v), menu_quantity: 1, topingsOrder: []}]}

My aim is to calculate the total for all items in this data so I would like to tap into it for example, I would like to tap into res_key using:

> const data = req.body.order
> const res = data['res_key']

Currently I am unable to read any parameter. Need help resolving this please.

My nodejs app settings are:

> app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true})); 
> app.use(express.json());

Comment: i'm not sure but I think express.json() works only if the appropriate application/json header is attached from the sender

Comment: Thanks. Here is the sending part:      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                      //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": 'http://localhost:54321',
                      //"Accept": "application/json",
                      "charset":"utf-8"
                    },

Comment: I think your data is not valid JSON. Valid JSON must have all keys and values in `"` quotes. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21661367/9967940)

Comment: It might be the case it seems. How can I fix this? My body request is like this: body: jsonEncode({'order'  : Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getOrder().toString()})

Comment: is this dart? I don't know any dart

Comment: Yes, it is dart. I am using flutter app to send this data.