# Why is my POST request not working when trying to insert form data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

This is my server side.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const { response } = require("express");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); 

app.post("/species", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req)
    const {name, description, img} = req.body
    const newSpecies = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO speciesdata (name, description, img ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *",
      [name, description, img]
    );
    console.log(newSpecies)
    res.json(newSpecies.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

I am not sure if i deconstruct the properties correctly for `req.body` as when i console log it, it returned an empty array.

This is my frontend side.

```
function AddspeciesForm() {

  const [Name, setName] = useState('');
  const [Description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [Image, setImage] = useState('');

  const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/species", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: Name,
          description: Description,
          img: Image
        })
      });
      
      const data = await response.json()
      console.log(data)

      window.location = "/";
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
}
```

As this is my first project that requires backend and frontend, I may have phrased my question in an awkward manner so hope you guys understand. Thank you in advance!

This is my postman request.
[image: Postman request]

**UPDATE 1**
When I changed the `content-type`  to `application/JSON` on my postman, the values are no longer null. And `req.body` returns the correct value. But in my frontend i have already specify that my `content-type: application/JSON`. So how do i bring in and display the changes on my application?

Comment: You don't need to use ```JSON.stringify``` when you send the request because you send it as a JSON format. If you use JSON.stringify, it will become a plain text.

Comment: you sure you have to use ```JSON.stringify()``` ?

Comment: Could it be that you need to move the call to `app.use(express.json()); ` before the `app.listen(port)`?

Comment: @Gpack Whats are the difference?

Comment: I have removed ```JSON.stringify()``` but it still returns an empty array

Comment: When using postman my result is giving me an array with the fields as the key but the values are all ```null```

Comment: Please try `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` in your backend and paste the result here.

Comment: It returned ```{}```

Comment: Can you verify that the request in the network view of the DevTools contains your JSON payload? If yes there might be something wrong with `app.use(express.json());`. You can also have a look on this issue (it sounds similar): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661047/node-js-express-json-middleware-not-parsing-request-as-expected

Comment: Hmm the request did not contain my JSON payload

Comment: @Derrick Tay I don't know if you can add middlewares to express after calling app.listen.

Comment: According to this documentation it is totally right to do `JSON.stringify`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Comment: Could there be an error in my ```app.post``` request such as the way i destructure the props?

Comment: If the payload isn't send from the client then your backend is not the problem. I expect two requests to be send by the browser. One of type OPTIONS for the CORS preflight request. If this succeeds the browser sends the real POST request with the payload. Can you try to send a hard coded json object like this and check if it arrives at your backend: `body: JSON.stringify({"name":"Name","description":"Description","img":"Image"})`

Comment: I have a question. Are the keys suppose to be strings also?

Comment: Yes in a valid JSON the keys must be strings surrounded by `"` but this should be ensured by calling `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Despite hardcoding, when using postman post request, it returns ```[{
        "id": 84,
        "name": null,
        "description": null,
        "img": null
    }
]```

Comment: And what did `console.log(req.body)` prints when you send the request with postman? You can also try a different browser (or disable browser addons which may infer) and check if it behaves differently.

Comment: still returns ```{}```

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong. It could help if you upload a screenshot of your postman request (method + url + body + headers).

Comment: Please try your request again with "raw" instead of "form-data" and for the body you have to use your JSON object. For example: `{"name":"Name","description":"Description","img":"Image"}`

Comment: Still no go... still giving me the fields will null value

Comment: OK but are there values in your `req.body` now? This must work in the first step. After this you can check if `pool.query` works correctly.

Comment: ```req.body``` still giving me ```{}```.

Comment: Can you also upload an image of the network view of your browsers DevTools. It should show the POST request for `/species` with all headers and the body/payload.

Comment: Not sure how to use that. It didnt return any POST request